# How do create a playback button for a voice record

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Hi there can anyone help me I have created a Play button for my voice recording app in silverlight 4 and i am not sure how to callback that wav. file that had been recorded and to play on my web page. Could any one help me please :)

I can record with record button, stop with stop button and save with save button but i do not know how to play the recorded wav. file before saving it.